# How do I keep my section footer stick at the end of one specific footer in table view swift

Tags: ios, swift, header, tableview, footer

I have some sections here and on section 1, I have this footer as an additional information.
But it keeps floating around when I scroll the screen. How do I stop that? How do I keep it under the section?
I'm using `viewForFooterInSection` and here's my code :

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let footerView = UIView()
    if section == 1 {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "A sticky footer here..."
        label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 16)
        label.textColor = UIColor.gray
        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        label.textAlignment = .left
        footerView.addSubview(label)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: footerView.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        label.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: footerView.leftAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        label.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: footerView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: footerView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }
    return footerView
}
```

I want to keep it sticky, under my section 1. How can I do that?

Thankyou in Advance

[image]

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, your `UITableView` should be grouped style in order to make footers stick to the sections and move along with them https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/style/grouped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should initialize your table view with the grouped style.

`let tableView = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .grouped)`

Comment: where should I put this code? I put it in `ViewDidLoad()` but didn't work yet

Comment: It would likely go outside of that function. If you are using interface builder, you can set the style to .grouped from the attributes panel.

Comment: I see what you trying to do man, thanks buddy it helped!